# Phonegap/Javascript App: how can I store cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies, cordova

I am exploring the idea of writing a javascript app for tablets which will read a personalized news site (which I do not own). I want to have the users login so they can see their content, but I don't know of a way to handle login cookies with javascript (ie store and resend them on each request).

Is this possible to do by writing some kind of interface to the native cookie store with Phonegap?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Phonegap does not provide any cookie abstraction, as there are plenty of other tools to do that already (Phonegap just wraps up smartphone functionality, not basic browser functionality).

If you're willing to use jQuery, you may want to try this [jquery-cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), I've used it successfully myself.

Comment: Does the jquery cookie plugin works on all the major platforms aka iOS, Blackberry, WP, etc?? TIA!!

Comment: Since it is a browser function it should work on every platform that has a browser.

Comment: I've been trying to get the cookie plugin to work, it will not store my cookie.

Comment: Well, try some other method then. Maybe something like http://hastebin.com/wanuqevafi.js - look up what you're able to do with the browser you're testing against