# How to remember that the user has pressed a button when reentering web app in Phonegap

Tags: php, javascript, android, html, cordova

I want to make my website skip the index.html file if the user has already clicked the Accept button, which redirects to the main website page.

I tried to use PHP to write to a .txt file and read its contents, but the website app being offline, I can't run PHP. Are there any simple ways to do such a thing offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

- Cookies
- localStorage
- sessionStorage

localStorage and sessionStorage are not good canditates as they get cleared very easily. So you should try [Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) (JavaScript cookies). you can keep the data offline with cookies and if the user has accepted it keep the information it in the cookies. cookies will be available even when the app is offline.

When app goes online keep updating the cookie that user agreed on user agreement.

Comment: I was just reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968209/phonegap-javascript-app-how-can-i-store-cookies, where they say that phonegap does not support cookies, but there is a [jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Comment: if cookies are not supported why not use `sqlite`? you can make a small table to keep the info that user accepted it or not. every time page loads check the [sqlite table](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)  and re-direct to the relevant page.

Comment: else consider 'localStorage` as there is no expiry date for it. [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) will be cleared only when you clear cache of the browser

Comment: I went for localStorage and it worked very well. Thanks a lot!